# Get a character from a screen position and put it in a string (not working)

Tags: assembly, nasm, x86-16, bios

I have a getchar function that is supposed to do this:

What it's supposed to output:

33

What it actually outputs:

3

Here is my current attempt:

```
char db 0
charcolor db 0
pos_x_2 db 0
pos_y_2 db 0
_getchar:
  MOV [pos_x_2], DL
  MOV [pos_y_2], DH
  MOV BH, 0
  MOV AH, 03h
  INT 0x10
  MOV [pos_x], DL
  MOV [pos_y], DH
  MOV DL, pos_x_2
  MOV DH, pos_y_2
  MOV AH, 02h
  INT 0x10
  MOV BH, 0
  MOV AH, 08h
  INT 0x10
  MOV [char], AL
  MOV [charcolor], AH
  RET
```

Comment: Using NASM with 16-bit code.

Comment: This code doesn't output anything.  It reads the current character/color at a specified location.  Check out the [definitions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/INT_10H) for the various int 10h functions.  Look at the value you are putting in ah to figure out which ones you are calling.

Comment: The main code is supposed to output both characters. It is only a snippet of the file.

Comment: Why would you post code that doesn't show the problem?  We can't tell you why the current code shows "3" instead of "33" if you don't show us the current code...

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> MOV DL, pos_x_2
> MOV DH, pos_y_2
> ```

In NASM the above does not load the values stored in the *pos_x_2* and *pos_y_2* variables. Instead, the registers are loaded with the low bytes of the addresses of these variables.
You need to use the square brackets like you did in the rest of your code.

Also, if you take the trouble to preserve the position of the cursor before reading anywhere on the screen, shouldn't you restore it before returning from the routine?
And note that you can preserve/restore `DL` and `DH` via a simple `push`/`pop` instead of using memory based variables.

```
; IN (dl,dh)
_getchar:
  push dx          ; On the stack is "Where we want to read from the screen"
  mov  bh, 0
  mov  ah, 03h     ; BIOS.GetCursor
  int  10h         ; -> CX DX
  pop  ax
  xchg ax, dx
  push ax          ; On the stack is "Where the cursor stood before"
  mov  ah, 02h     ; BIOS.SetCursor
  int  10h
  mov  ah, 08h     ; BIOS.ReadCharacterAndAttribute
  int  10h         ; -> AX
  mov  [char], ax  ; (*)
  pop  dx          ; Restore the cursor to where it stood before
  mov  ah, 02h     ; BIOS.SetCursor
  int  10h
  ret

  ...

char db 0
charcolor db 0
```

(*) Because the *char* and *charcolor* variables are adjacent in memory and in the correct order, you can write the values from `AL` and `AH` in one go from `AX`.

Comment: I might have used `pop ax` / `push dx` / `mov dx, ax` so there are fewer mental steps to follow for which data goes where.  xchg is still usable as a size optimization instead of 2-byte `mov`, if you care about speed on real 8086 instead of speed on later CPUs.  (Although it's dominated by `int` costs so might as well go for code-size.)